# Programmatically set the Background color of a Drawable in Android?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have an image in a resource file.

```
Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

The image has a transparent background.

Is there a way to programmatically set the background color to the Drawable before using the end product further in my code?

Comment: so you want to change the color of my_imagw?

Comment: It has a transparent background currently, this particular png resource with some image. So I want to change the color of the background to something else leaving the inner image intact.

Comment: see Drawable.setColorFilter

Comment: That affects the color of my image though, I want to be filling the transparent pixels.
I'm still looking through to see if there is a way to modify transparent ones instead though.

Comment: so what do you want to do with transparent pixels?

Comment: It's the transparent pixels I want to be changed to another color.

Comment: what porter duff modes did you try ?

Comment: my_drawable.setColorFilter(hex_color, PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY);

That one works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Drawing with PorterduffXferMode may help you in your case. This way you can merge two images (your image and a overlay completly in your color you want to replace the transparent pixels with) in many different ways.

Different porterduff modes explaned:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mer0918/

Android example:
http://www.vogella.com/code/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.html

This way you draw the result inside a new Bitmap. (SRC_OVER should work in your case if your image is the src and the background is used as the dst)

Answer (score 0):

`setColorFilter()` with Porterduff `SRC` will break the transparent of drawable.

I used this in my code, and it work

```
disabledIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), resId);
disabledIcon = DrawableCompat.wrap(disabledIcon);
disabledIcon.mutate(); // to not share its state with any other drawable
DrawableCompat.setTint(disabledIcon, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.button_text_disabled));
```